# What did George Orwell think of the USSR before travelling to Spain?

Tags: george-orwell

George Orwell volunteered to fight in the Spanish Civil War. After being wounded on the front line, he went to Barcelona and was caught up in the suppression of the POUM militia by the Spanish Communists. This incident soured him on the USSR and communism for the rest of his life. It led him to write *Homage to Catalonia*, a denunciation of Soviet propaganda and influence in Spain, and ultimately *1984*, a book-length nightmare of the totalitarian future.

Before Orwell travelled to Spain in 1937, what was his opinion of the Soviet Union? Was he always against it? Was he ever for it?